# Looping to calculate rainfall monthly

Tags: r, time-series, interpolation

In GRASS GIS I have access to a table in PostgreSQL Database with this structure:

Table Name: `rainfall_time_serie`s

Columns: `id | year | month | day | value_mm | x | y | gauge_code`

Setting g.region (GRASS command) to the Watershed limits, I need create for each month, one interpolated raster, representing the rainfall. This times-series is very huge, has 17 years, my question is: is it possible to do this operation with a looping? it is probably easier using SQL "GROUP BY" clause wtih a counter, but I'm newbie in R.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is definately off-topic for this site, and I've voted to migrate to Stackoverflow. You may also be interested to know about the [GIS Q/A site](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/751/andy-w) as well though. If you wanted to do the calculations directly in GRASS that would be a good site to ask.

Comment: Are you creating 12 monthly averages for the 17 years of data? How dense is your data. What kind of interpolation do you want to do? B-splines, IDW, or some form of kriging etc? Provide some code and what you have attempted so far and you may get some better feedback. Also try posting to r-sig-geo (but make sure you reference this post). I also suggest reading the paper associated with the WorldClim database: [Very high resolution interpolated climate surfaces for global land areas](http://www.worldclim.org/worldclim_IJC.pdf)

Comment: And when you say... "very huge", what do you mean? There are methods beyond base package for dealing with data that are "very huge" if necessary.